# Cyfe not allowing php string in custom widget table

Tags: php, echo

I am making a dashboard using http://www.cyfe.com/ where i want to have a table containing some of my GA data.Under `New widgets->custom->Private URL->` then `configure widget->chart type->table`

I referred [Cyfe](http://www.cyfe.com/custom) in tables section example

```
Sales Rep,Revenue($),Sales
Jane Doe,100132,213
Crystal Smith,52035,102
Jack Carter,10342,54
Mona Junior,5413,21
Homer Simpson,100,1
```

in to my php if i code it in style where each new line has part of echo like:

```
<?php
echo "Sales Rep,Revenue($),Sales  
Jane Doe,100132,213  
Crystal Smith,52035,102  
Jack Carter,10342,54  
Mona Junior,5413,21  
Homer Simpson,100,1";
?>
```

then I get my table formed but if i write it in single line

```
 <?php
    echo "Sales Rep,Revenue($),Sales Jane Doe,100132,213 Crystal Smith,52035,102 Jack Carter,10342,54 Mona Junior,5413,21 Homer Simpson,100,1";
    ?>
```

it creates all of them as labels.

In both the cases i have o/p as

```
Sales Rep,Revenue($),Sales Jane Doe,100132,213 Crystal Smith,52035,102 Jack Carter,10342,54 Mona Junior,5413,21 Homer Simpson,100,1
```

Any suggestion how can i echo my ga api data in order to support cyfe format?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe asking the Cyfe support will yield better results than posting here; it's a proprietary product, not too many people who can help you with it here I'd imagine.

Comment: @deceze Cool thanks... I though may be coding in some other style  would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the second example isn't working is because the data isn't split into separate lines.

Try splitting your data with the "\n" character like this:

```
<?php

echo "Sales Rep,Revenue($),Sales\nJane Doe,100132,213\nCrystal Smith,52035,102\nJack Carter,10342,54\nMona Junior,5413,21\nHomer Simpson,100,1";

?>
```

For further assistance with this please contact our support. Thanks! :)